# Simple way to check if redux state changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a story reducer with state that constantly changes based on actions that users perform, I'd like to show "Save changes" indicator when story gets changed and the only way I can think about to do this is to attach something to each action that changes state to know if it was performed hence affected state of the story. However, I have a lot of these and it would be better if there was a simple way to check if redux state changed and show "Save changes" indicator based on that.

Comment: I've found redux to have some good things of course but tradeoffs from basic programming paradigms we love like a simple callback or that something happened. Probably doing a dispatched event after something happened is a happy medium from Flux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like maybe you just want to [subscribe to dispatches on the store](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe) and check if state has actually changed from the last time and show your indicator based on that.

Comment: Is it possible to observe changes for a part of state?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try a logger?

https://github.com/fcomb/redux-logger

I've found it immensely helpful in debugging anything in my stores by checking the state after each action.